# how to improve the parsing performance?

Tags: parsing, antlr

I've taken the presto grammar in this link and tried to adopt it to my needs:
https://github.com/prestodb/presto/blob/master/presto-parser/src/main/antlr4/com/facebook/presto/sql/parser/SqlBase.g4

in order to also support snowflake copy into I've added the following:
in the statement section:

```
    COPY INTO target = qualifiedName
      ('(' qualifiedName (',' qualifiedName)*  ')' )?
      FROM (query | source = snowflakeLocations)
      ~(';')*?                                                                                #snowflakeCopyInto
```

and:

```
snowflakeLocations
    : internal_stage | external_stage | external_location
    ;

internal_stage
    : ((identifier '.')?  '@%'? identifier ('/'  identifier '/'?)? |
      '@' TILDE ('/' identifier)? )
    ;

external_stage
    : identifier ('/' identifier '/'?)?
    ;

external_location
    : string ~(';')*?
    ;
```

Things are now working and I'm able to parse all correctly but they are running more than twice slower.

Any idea what can be done to improve performance?

Thanks,
Nir.

Comment: The grammar seems a little strange. How do you distinguish a derivation of `snowflakeLocations => internal_stage => 
((identifier '.')?  '@%'? identifier ('/'  identifier '/'?)? => identifier`
vs. `snowflakeLocations => external_stage => identifier ('/' identifier '/'?)? => identifier`?? You have `~(';')*?` at the tail of `external_location` and also the `COPY INTO target` rule as well.

Comment: yeah, I see your point. Do you think this might be causing the performance issue?

Comment: Hard to say if that is the cause of the performance issue. I would try to fix the grammar then recheck the runtimes.

Comment: @kaby76 - removed the external location completely. Still things are very slow.

Comment: in fact, when removing the ~(';')*? at the end of COPY INTO target things are back to normal.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by slower--compared to what? With the original grammar, I wrote two C# programs that test the original grammar against the grammar with your changes. I augmented both grammars with an additional rule for ';' separated statements, renamed "base" to "base_" to get it to compile in C#, and then parsed a string with 100k copies of a CREATE TABLE. How do you compare the runtimes for input with new Sql statements that didn't exist in the original grammar? The programs run with the same runtime of 16 s. (https://github.com/kaby76/AntlrExamples/tree/master/SqlBase)

Comment: Ok, got it. Glad you found the problem.

Comment: @kaby76- sorry for the mixup. I meant with other queries I'm parsing (I have around 400 in my unit tests).
this solved the current issue. However, I'm still seeking to improve performance. Tried the same trick in some other places but couldn't see any improvement. 
Tried also to use the Prediction_Model.ssl and only if fails use Predication_Model.LL, but this gave my improvement of only 6.3%. 
Any other idea?

Comment: There are two types of optimizations you can do to improve performance. Unfolding is the transformation of substitution of the RHS of the rule into an occurrence of the LHS symbol in another rule. When unfolding is done, the original rule is expanded in size, and it makes for a less readable rule, but faster one. A second transformation is to replace rule factoring with EBNF rules. If you look at the "expression" rule, it can derive "booleanExpression", then "valueExpression" and so on. Rather than this, you can rewrite multiple rules as one rule where the alts are ordered in priority.

Comment: @kaby76- the second option is clear and I'll give it a try. regarding the first one, is there any relevant link where I can read more?
Many Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Nir99, Check out this [article](http://codinggorilla.com/?p=2594) from my blog. Halupka'14 has a nice summary of the various transforms and why you'd employ them, free pdf to boot. Some transforms, like conversion to EBNF, are Antlr specific, so they won't be anywhere. Note, before you do optimizations, you should profile your grammar to know what is really the problem for your input. Count up how many node types to see what's being called the most. It's just like perf tuning any other code, you always start with the methods that are called the most, or take the longest.

Comment: @kaby76 - thanks, looks super helpful!. I'll give it try and see how it goes.

Comment: @kaby76 you should reformulate your comments into a solution.

Comment: @peter.cyc I'm not sure what I would say, except that the grammar looks "strange" because there are multiple derivations possible. I'm guessing that Interpreter.AdaptivePredict() is trying to decide which parse it prefers, taking more time than usual. It's just a feeling--I didn't debug and profile this with a perf tool, then formulate an explanation of what the Antlr RTN parser is doing. But, there might be more to this to explore.